# Efficient way to animate Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been looking for a way to animate a shrinking/growing effect for a grid in one of my applications: The idea is that a UI button would shrink or grow a side bar.

I [found](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/da47a4b8-4d39-4d6e-a570-7dbe51a842e4/gridlengthanimation?forum=wpf) a suggested solution, by creating a new GridLength animation class. The class accomplishes my goal, but it is very choppy, and I'd rather not have visible hangups in the animation.

On that same thread, others suggest to use a child item in an auto-sized grid column/row to take advantage of an animation, but I find this solution to be a bit cumbersome: I depend on these child items to define the shape of the column, and I'd rather not. It also poses some complications for me, if I chose to define the animation in XAML.

Does anyone know of a clean way to accomplish a grid column/row animation?

To help, this is the class for animation I am using:

```
/// <summary>
/// Animates a grid length value just like the DoubleAnimation animates a double value
/// </summary>
public class GridLengthAnimation : AnimationTimeline
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the type of object to animate
    /// </summary>
    public override Type TargetPropertyType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(GridLength);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an instance of the animation object
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns the instance of the GridLengthAnimation</returns>
    protected override System.Windows.Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new GridLengthAnimation();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency property for the From property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FromProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("From", typeof(GridLength),
            typeof(GridLengthAnimation));

    /// <summary>
    /// CLR Wrapper for the From depenendency property
    /// </summary>
    public GridLength From
    {
        get
        {
            return (GridLength)GetValue(GridLengthAnimation.FromProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(GridLengthAnimation.FromProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency property for the To property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("To", typeof(GridLength),
            typeof(GridLengthAnimation));

    /// <summary>
    /// CLR Wrapper for the To property
    /// </summary>
    public GridLength To
    {
        get
        {
            return (GridLength)GetValue(GridLengthAnimation.ToProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(GridLengthAnimation.ToProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Animates the grid let set
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="defaultOriginValue">The original value to animate</param>
    /// <param name="defaultDestinationValue">The final value</param>
    /// <param name="animationClock">The animation clock (timer)</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the new grid length to set</returns>
    public override object GetCurrentValue(object defaultOriginValue,
        object defaultDestinationValue, AnimationClock animationClock)
    {
        double fromVal = ((GridLength)GetValue(GridLengthAnimation.FromProperty)).Value;
        //check that from was set from the caller
        if (fromVal == 1)
            //set the from as the actual value
            fromVal = ((GridLength)defaultDestinationValue).Value;

        double toVal = ((GridLength)GetValue(GridLengthAnimation.ToProperty)).Value;

        if (fromVal > toVal)
            return new GridLength((1 - animationClock.CurrentProgress.Value) * (fromVal - toVal) + toVal, GridUnitType.Star);
        else
            return new GridLength(animationClock.CurrentProgress.Value * (toVal - fromVal) + fromVal, GridUnitType.Star);
    }
}
```

This is a look at what my column style animation looks like:

```
<ColumnDefinition.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSideBarOpen}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <core:GridLengthAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                            From="1*" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" >
                                        </core:GridLengthAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <core:GridLengthAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                            From="0" To="1*" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
     </ColumnDefinition.Style>
```

Comment: What does your grid definition look like?  If there is any relative (star) sizing, resizing one column will cause multiple measurements to fix this relative sizing, and you will likely get a lot of choppiness and other UI ugliness.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Wonko. I am using relative sizing, so your answer makes sense to me. The real trouble is, I played with an animation involving fixed sizing, and a curious thing happened: I would define the width of the column to be 150, and in the animation define the animation from 150 to 0, and all of a sudden, the side bare filled over half the window. It seems there is some sort of discrepancy between the values given by the GridLength in the column definition, and the GridLength inside the GridLengthAnimation.

Anything that might help address this would be appreciated.